# How to make a Slack App/Bot post a code block (Python)

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

In Slack you're able to post as a user in a code block like in Stackoverflow

```
like so
```

As a posting user, you're able to do this by typing "```" it then changes your input box to one formatted for code.

I need to get my Slack App/Bot to post a Tabluate Table as a code block so the formatting stays consistent with my Python output. At the moment, my code looks like this:

````
client.chat_postMessage(channel="#google-analytics-test",text="```" + table)
````

This simply posts the table in a text format with "```" added onto the start of it.

#### This is what comes from the bot:

[image: This is what comes from the bot]

#### How it should look coming from the user:

[image: How it should look coming from the user]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, any alternative methods to get the Tabulate Table being posted by the bot in the right format would also be very welcomed!

Answer (score 15):

You also need "```" after the table and both should be in a separate line. This should do it:

````
client.chat_postMessage(channel="#google-analytics-test",text="```\n" + table + "\n```")
````

Note the added newlines "\n".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `chat_postMessage` isn't splitting your text into separate messages -- happened to me at ~25 lines.

Docs are a bit vague on expected behavior: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#truncating

> For best results, limit the number of characters in the text field to 4,000 characters. Ideally, messages should be short and human-readable. Slack will truncate messages containing more than 40,000 characters. If you need to post longer messages, please consider uploading a snippet instead.